# TinyMCE 5.0.6+ and WordCountUpdate event

Tags: tinymce, word-count, tinymce-plugins, tinymce-5

So TinyMCE 5.0.6 or later contains a [wordcount plugin](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/wordcount/).

I want to use it to count characters and echo the character count to the screen.

Apparently there is also a [WordCountUpdate](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/advanced/events/#wordcountevents) event that I can listen for.

**How do I listen for the "WordCountUpdate" event?**

Answer (score 0):

Just worked it out, here is an example for others:

```
<script>
    tinymce.init({
        selector: 'textarea',
        plugins: "wordcount",
        toolbar: "wordcount",
        init_instance_callback: function (editor) {
            var charcount = document.getElementById("charcount");
            editor.on('WordCountUpdate', function (e) {
                charcount.innerHTML = e.wordCount.characters;
                console.log(e);
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Have you worked out a way to use this function to then validate based on character or word count?